# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detach' of null

Tags: extjs, null, typeerror, detach

I am working on a project developed in Sencha ( a javascript framework ) and i am totally new in it.
right Now I am facing an issue i.e  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detach' of null".
I have no idea over this error and didn't knew when and why it is coming , it occurs randomly in project.
Any one please help me if any one knew about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Share code snippet or [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) for what you have done so far.

Comment: Cant share the snippet because i really dont have any idea where the error occurs and code is really massive,
But when i debug this, I got that the point refers to this line

   "  removeInnerItem: function(item) {
            item.element.detach();
    }  "  in  " app\touch\src\layout\Default.js "

Comment: Use the browser's dev tools to break on uncaught errors. Look at the variables and maybe walk up the callstack while still looking at the variables. Find out what is trying to detach an null'd element. This likely occurs on an already destroyed component.

Comment: @MitchellSimoens - Thanks for your suggestion, I follow on you footsteps, made breakpoints and just found the error line.  It only needs to Destroy the container and reassign the new value over it. Assigning new value without destroying container causes " Detach of null " issue.